# (HTML) Entire list of Divs?

Tags: html, css, list

I would like to know all the different types of div classes. I have a small amount of understanding of divs.

Here's an example of how I would use a div and then customise the content in the div using CSS.

```
div .header {
    font-family: "Bebas";
    font-size: 25;
    font-color: #00FF00;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: 120px;
    bottom: 1095px;
}
```

So, if you're not following my question(s), what I want to know is;

- A. Does that code look alright?
- B. How many div classes are there, and what are they called?
- and C. Could someone give me a brief explanation as to what they are and more specifically, how to use them.

I'm mostly self-taught, in case you wondered.

Comment: It looks like you don't know anything about HTML/CSS. You should start learning before doing anything else. Here's a tutorial: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously said, you can set as many div classes as you'd like, they're not preset. I would also recommend doing the Codecademy tutorials.

Looking at your code, you're telling the div to float: right; - fine. Then you use position: relative; followed by right: and bottom: values. Either float or position, no need to do both.

The way you've written the rule is probably not how you mean it. It's currently looking for this -

```
<div>
    <div class="header">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

- An element with the class header that's inside a div.

You should remove the space so your rule becomes -

```
div.header {
    enter code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, everyone. Yeah, the float was put in there by accident, I realised after I posted. #AmateurHour. Thanks for the links, too, I'll check them out. I'm too lazy to say 'thanks' for every answer, so hopefully one universal thanks will do. :)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question you can have as many div as you want. and you assign class or id to identify each div.  just be aware id are unique, you can not assign the same id to more than one elements.

and your css format is right, but I am not sure why you declare right/bottom those will only render when your position is absolute with out float.

I would suggest you go through some tutorial at http://www.codecademy.com.  it's free. and don't required any sign up, unless you want to save your progress.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code you wrote looks fine. I don't know what you intended to do with this code, so going by just the syntax it looks fine.

Coming to your sub-question B and C,

`div` is block level element with almost no specific task or objective. They are general purpose elements used for most tasks. Block level elements act as containers and `div` is the most basic type of container we get.

We can use `div` to store other elements, design web document and proper indention of text and images and what not.

Answer (score 0):

Let's answer your questions one by one:

A - Your code looks fine ( depending on your needs ).

B - You can use as many div classes as you like.

C - Simply you can use div classes to describe it's content like: `div.header` , `div.body` , `div.footer` and so on.
But i recommend to use the new HTML5 semantic tags instead, it is easy, clear and more powerful with search engine optimization.

For more clarification, kindly check the following link [www.itibooks.com/html/html5-semantics](http://www.itibooks.com/html/html5-semantics) .